# How to make UICollectionview cell height dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIcollectionview`. There are some cells of the Collectionview. Inside that `CollectionviewCell` there is a textview. The textview's content is dynamic. So the cell height should be dynamic.

How to do that?

Comment: you can always create a custom layout for that, it is possible if you change the height of certain cells, you may need to change the actual location some other cells which the bigger cells would overlap – and a custom layout is a perfect place to handle that situation.

Answer (score 3):

1-Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol. 
2-Conform to protocol by implement the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method in your `ViewController`. 
3-Use the index of the cell to get the text you have and calculate the height and width of it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let constraintRect = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.max)
     let data = myTextArray[indexpath.row];
     let boundingBox = data.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: Constants.strings.fontName, size: 30)!], context: nil)
     return CGSizeMake(boundingBox.width, boundingBox.height); //(width,hight)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the last cell is behaving differently. All the cells are drawn as expected but the leading of the last cell is more than the others cell. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Use NSAttributedString in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` to calculate rect for the height and width:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let attString = NSAttributedString(string: self.rows[indexPath.row], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)])
    var r: CGRect = attString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

    return r.size

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the last cell is behaving differently. All the cells are drawn as expected but the leading of the last cell is more than the others cell. Any suggestion?

Comment: If textView use different font and size you must add 'NSFontAttributeName' to 'NSAttributedString' to calculate correct size

Answer (score 0):

1) Override collectionflowlayout delegate method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(50, 50); //(width,hight)
}
```

2) In above method, Calculate the height of textview which contains dynamic length and add that value in your fixed height. `Ex. cellHeight = 100 + textview height. //100 is height which not contain textview height.`

3) After calculating height, replace it in above method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSizeMake(50, dynamicheight); //(width,hight)
    }
```